# UIButton setTitle doesn't work

Tags: swift, uibutton, xcode6

I'm trying to change the text of a UIButton when it gets clicked.  I've tried the following things, which failed:

First I tried inserting a button on the storyboard and linking it to the view controller, with the code for the button appearing like this:

```
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {}.
```

Within the button's parentheses, I then used

```
button.setTitle ("something" , for State: .Selected)
```

However, when I run this code in the simulator, it doesn't seem to work at all.

I have also tried, following the Apple reference manual, to set different labels for different states in the side menu after clicking on said button, but still this didn't work.
Can anyone tell me exactly (i.e. what code to write and where exactly it goes) how to make this happen?

Comment: Post code if you want help. We have no idea what your working with.

Comment: you are right, sorry. I hadn't figured out how to make the code appear in the grey box for easier readability

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The type of the sender should be UIButton, when creating the IBAction function.
The **sender** is your button. The function is called when you tap on the button. You must use the function **setTitle** on the sender(your button).

```
@IBAction func buttonTouchedUpInside(sender: UIButton) { 
    sender.setTitle("buttonName", forState: .normal)
}
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much! you have no idea how long I have been trying to understand how it worked! And then you finally explained it to me! by the way, where can I find info on these types of questions? Is the Swift programming language guide the right resource for this? And one more thing, how would I then turn the button back to the original label when I click it again? I know you can create a "toggle" function that has two states kind of thing, but I have very little idea on how to write it. thanks again

Comment: @JustABeginner Just to answer one part of your question: you can find solution to your problems very easy when you google your problem (write the programming language in the search field, too) then the first 3 results are often from stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you iCode, I had actually tried googling it for this one, but none of the answers I found were clear to me :/

Answer (score 19):

## Swift 4:

#### Plain Title

The `setTitle()` method will work for titles that are "Plain" as defined in the button's Attributes inspector.

```
@IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) { 
     sender.setTitle("buttonName", for: .normal)
}
```

#### Attributed Title

The `setTitle()` method has no effect on a button's title if it's configured as "Attributed" in the Attributes inspector.  To manage this situation, first get the attributed title from the button, then set the value.

```
@IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) { 
     let attributedTitle = sender.attributedTitle(for: .normal)
     attributedTitle?.setValue("buttonName", forKey: "string")
     sender.setAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: I own you hours of my life. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In practically, if you use button from Storyboard or Xib file, and not clear button value in (Storyboard, Xib), than setTitle method doesn't work. If you cleared button value, setTitle method is work.

Answer (score 2):

Create an IBOutlet for your button, then this code should work (assuming you named your IBOutlet `button`):

```
button.setTitle("title", forState: .Normal)
button.setTitle("title 1", forState: .Application)
button.setTitle("title 2", forState: .Highlighted)
button.setTitle("title 3", forState: .Reserved)
button.setTitle("title 4", forState: .Selected)
button.setTitle("title 5", forState: .Disabled)
```

place it in your `viewDidLoad()` method.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.btnAssment setTitle:@"ASSDate" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let button = UIButton()
button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue, and none of the answer here worked in my case.

For me the solution was to call `button.layoutSubviews()` to update UIButton's label just after i changed the title.

(also I had to change the button type to custom, otherwise the title change would blink)